# sed: Can my pattern contain an "is not" character? How do I say "is not X"?

Tags: regex, sed

How do I say "is not" a certain character in `sed`?

Comment: `[^X]` is any char but `X`. PS though we know what you mean, SED should not be capitalised

Comment: @Sanjay Okay I will un-capitalize sed. Can you post an answer in the answer section next time, not the comments?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
[^x]
```

This is a character class that accepts any character except `x`.

Comment: I'll add a warning from Mastering Regular Expressions. Note that for this to match there must be something there. The regex 'su[^x]' will match 'sum' and 'sun' but not 'su'.

Comment: How do you fix it match the case you mentioned 'su' ?

Comment: @jcalfee314, I believe it should work to add a ? to it like 'su[^x]?' meaning it should match zero or one of those characters.

Comment: @GradysGhost No; a trailing repeat is almost never what you want; it means match with or without this final restriction.

Comment: So to spell this out, `su[^x]\?` will match "sux" because the substring "su" satisfies the regular expression. You are excluding the x from the match, not preventing something with an x there from matching. (This could work if there is something after the condition, like `su[^x]\?$`)

Comment: +1 for answering the question as asked, but might be worthwhile to provide an edit suggesting the use of **alternation** to solve the common practical case people like @jcalfee314 are asking about, where "su[!x]" is intended to also match "su" without any characters after it: `\(su[^x]\|su$\)` (I think the shorter form `su\([^x]\|$\)` might also work).

Answer (score 18):

For those **not satisfied with the selected answer** as per [johnny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520704/sed-can-my-pattern-contain-an-is-not-character-how-do-i-say-is-not-x#comment9115849_7520735).

`su[^x]` will match `sum` and `sun` but not `su`.

You can tell sed to `not` match lines with `x` using the syntax below:

```
sed '/x/! s/su//' file
```

[See kkeller's answer for another example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178023)

Comment: This would alse skip `x su` even though it's supposed to match. You could do `/sux/!s/su//` but that will still skip `su sux`where perhaps the first, but not the second, `su` should match. Ideally, the OP should clarify the requirements.

Comment: @tripleee The robust solution is `\(su[^x]\|su$\)` (I think the shorter form `su\([^x]\|$\)` might also work).

Answer (score 10):

There are two possible interpretations of your question. Like others have already pointed out, `[^x]` matches a single character which is not `x`. But an empty string also isn't `x`, so perhaps you are looking for `[^x]\|^$`.

Neither of these answers extend to multi-character sequences, which is usually what people are looking for. You could painstakingly build something like

```
[^s]\|s\($\|[^t]\|t\($\|[^r]\)\)\)
```

to compose a regular expression which doesn't match `str`, but a much more straightforward solution in `sed` is to delete any line which *does* match `str`, then keep the rest;

```
sed '/str/d' file
```

Perl 5 introduced a much richer regex engine, which is hence standard in Java, PHP, Python, etc. Because Perl helpfully supports a subset of `sed` syntax, you could probably convert a simple `sed` script to Perl to get to use a useful feature from this extended regex dialect, such as negative assertions:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:(?!str).)+/not/' file
```

will replace a string which is not `str` with `not`. The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group (unlike in many `sed` dialects, an unescaped parenthesis is a metacharacter in Perl) and `(?!str)` is a negative assertion; the text immediately after this position in the string mustn't be `str` in order for the regex to match. The `+` repeats this pattern until it fails to match. Notice how the assertion needs to be true at every position in the match, so we match one character at a time with `.` (newbies often get this wrong, and erroneously only assert at e.g. the beginning of a longer pattern, which could however match `str` somewhere within, leading to a "leak").

Comment: +1 Right after the "delete every line which *does* match" `sed` example line, I would also include a "or operate on every line that *does not* match" with a simple `sed` example of how to do that too. (Like `sed '/str/! { ... }` which I think works, but if I'm wrong then there is always `:`, `b` and `t` to build arbitrary conditional branches with.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the provided answers , you can negate a character class in sed , using the notation `[^:[C_CLASS]:]` , for example , `[^[:blank:]]` will match anything which is not considered a space character .

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, and the below post supports this, sed doesn't support normal regex negation using "^".  I don't think sed has a direct negation method...but if you check the below post, you'll see some workarounds.
[Sed regex and substring negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053100/sed-regex-and-substring-negation)

Comment: Sort of.. this works: echo '<a href="egww">blah</a><a href="http://bloge.weg">yeah</a>' | sed 's@href="[^http]@href="/@g'

Comment: Outputs: <a href="/gww">blah</a><a href="http://bloge.weg">yeah</a> (only matched the relative url)

Comment: This is incorrect. `sed` supports `[^...]` negation just fine. Perhaps your understanding of this construct is incomplete, though? The linked question is useful, though.

Comment: But notice that `[^http]` looks for a single character which is not (newline or) h,t, or p. (The second t is completely redundant, but tolerated by the regex engine.)