# using awk and gensub to remove the part in a string ending with "character+number+S"

Tags: shell, design-patterns, awk, substitution

My goal is to remove the end "1S" as well as the letter immediately before it, in this case "M". How do I achieve that? My non-working code :

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" | gawk '{gensub(/([^(1S)]*)[a-zA-Z](1S$)/, "\\1", "g") ; print $0}'
>14M3856N61M1S
```

The desired results should be

```
>14M3856N61
```

Some additional information here . 1. I do not think substr will work here since  my actual target strings would come with various lengths. 2. I prefer not to take the approach of defining special delimiter because this would be used together with "if" as part of the awk conditional operation while the 
 delimiter is already defined globally. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `echo "14M3856N61M1S" | sed 's/.1S$//'`

Comment: @Cyrus, Thanks. I prefer a awk solution since I am applying it to be part of the awk script with conditional operation.

Comment: It looks like you are hoping that `[^(1S)]` will do something it doesn't do. It matches a single character which is not `(` or `1` or `S` or `)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed: Can my pattern contain an “is not” character? How do I say “is not X”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520704/sed-can-my-pattern-contain-an-is-not-character-how-do-i-say-is-not-x/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a simple substitution to match the `1S` at the last and match any character before it?

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk '{sub(/[[:alnum:]]{1}1S$/,"")}1'
14M3856N61M1S
```

Here the `[[:alnum:]]` corresponds the POSIX character class to match alphanumeric characters (digits and alphabets) and `{1}` represent to match just one. Or if you are sure about only `characters` could occur before the pattern `1S`, replace `[[:alnum:]]` with `[[:alpha:]]`.

To answer OP's question to put the match result on a separate variable, use `match()` as `sub()` does not return the substituted string but only the count of number of substitutions made.

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk 'match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{1}1S$/){str=substr($0,1,RSTART-1); print str}'
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment I am adding solutions where OP could get the result into a bash variable too as follows.

```
var=$(echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]1S$/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)}' )
echo "$var"
14M3856N61
```

---

---

Could you please try following too.

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]1S$/){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)} 1'
14M3856N61
```

***Explanation of above command:***

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" |        ##printing sample string value by echo command here and using |(pipe) for sending standard ouptut of it as standard input to awk command.
awk '                         ##Starting awk command here.
  match($0,/[a-zA-Z]1S$/){    ##using match keyword of awk here to match 1S at last of the line along with an alphabet(small or capital) before it too.
   $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)   ##If match found in above command then re-creating current line and keeping its value from 1 to till RSTART-1 value where RSTART and RLENGTH values are set by match out of the box variables by awk.
  }                           ##Closing match block here.
1'                            ##Mentioning 1 will print the edited/non-edited values of lines here.
```

Comment: this is indeed pretty close to what I tried to achieve. Very much appreciated !

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, I am learning how to do just that. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk -F '.1S$' '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
14M3856N61
```

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of myself too. I prefer not to define the delimiter as it's already defined globally in the overall awk code. Thank you though, for taking the time to respond.

Comment: With its own array and separator: `echo "14M3856N61M1S" | awk '{split($1,a,".1S$"); print a[1]}'`

Comment: A neat solution. Cool. Thank you !