# How to set a upper limit on regex repetition

Tags: regex

If I have a string and I need to write a regex pattern to find match only for `a` and `aa`, but not more than 2 consecutive `a`. For instance, `baaab` is not a match because 3 `a` appear together, but `abaa` is a match. Can I write a regex pattern for this purpose?

Here are something that I tried:

- `pattern = 'a{1,2}'`, but this pattern also matches `'baaab'`.
- `pattern = 'a{1,2}[^a]'`, but it failed to match `'abaa'`
- `pattern = 'a{1,2}[^a]?'`, but it also matches `'baaab'`

So what's the correct pattern I should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520704/sed-can-my-pattern-contain-an-is-not-character-how-do-i-say-is-not-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead assertion which enforces that three or more a's do not appear:

```
^(?!.*aaa).*a{1,2}.*$
```

### Demo