# sed match lines not containing expression with parenthesis

Tags: c++, c, sed

(I have legacy C+ code that compiles with warnings with gcc and fails with errors with clang. The method signatures are either `function(int,(char*),(char*)) or function(int,string,string)`. This method is used **a lot** throughout the code.)

So in trying to normalize the calls i'm giving it a go with sed.
Assuming this input:

```
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");   // 1
function(DEFINED_VAR,(char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");    // 2
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char *)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, "Class::method42()");         // 3
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*) someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, "Class::method42()");         // 4
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char *)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");  // 5
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");   // 6
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char *)"Class::method42()");  // 7
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, ( char* )"Class::method42()"); // 8
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, "Class::method42()");          // 9
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");   // 10
function(DEFINED_VAR, ( char* )someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, "Class::method42()");        // 11
function(DEFINED_VAR, (char*)someMethod(OTHER_VAR).c_str() + more->stuff, (char*)"Class::method42()");   // 12
```

I want lines 3, 4, 9 and 11 to end with `(char*)"whateverstring");`

What i've tried so far:

```
sed -n '/^\s*function\s*(\s*\w.*,\s*(\s*char\s*\*.*,\s*\([^(]\|$\)/p' inputfile.cpp
```

but i can't quite exclude the second "(char*)" occurrence to skip the correct lines.

[1831722](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520735/1831722) and [1831722](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053163/1831722) are close (i prefer the former) but the `(` is eluding me.

What am i missing? I'm using GNU sed on Ubuntu Xenial. I'm cool with awk (but i don't think it allows for capturing pattern matches) or perl, if whatever is needed here isn't easy.

The VARs and "string" may vary and i'm already accounting for spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using address range, you could apply substitution on lines not matching two consecutive `(char *\*)`:

```
sed '/\(char *\*\).*\(char *\*\)/!s/\("[^"]*");\)/(char*)&/' inputfile.cpp
```

**Edit:**

To make sure substitutions apply only on function definitions, just change the substitution pattern:

```
sed '/\(char *\*\).*\(char *\*\)/!s/\(^ *function.*\)\("[^"]*");\)/\1(char*)\2/' inputfile.cpp
```

Comment: I'll have to look into that `s//!s///` syntax but it seems as though that would match *any* like with "char *" occurrences, not just these specific lines.